# How to set device by device whether audio output should switch upon connecting

Tags: 20.04, sound, devices, output

Is it possible on Ubuntu 20.04 to automatically switch the sound output device for some devices and not for others?

Specifically I want to switch to some devices such as headphones but my screen for some reason shows up as a non-functioning Ditigal Output and I never want to switch to this automatically.

So preferably I would keep the automatic switching behavior on connecting for most devices but have a blacklist for devices for which I don't want to switch. Alternatively I would like to never switch except for a whitelist of devices. Or if neither is possible I would like to be asked each time a new output device is connected.

Is any of this possible?